# Zoom in a polar chart matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

**Note: My code is at the end of the question.

I want to recreate this chart in matplotlib:
[image]

I have come a long way of making something similar but I am stuck in the last part, which is to zoom in the plot to remove all the white space. So basically, I want to zoom in to the red box:

Note that the grid will be removed on the actual chart. Displaying it now to explain what I would like done.

[image: from pylab import *]

Is that possible? My code is here:
https://github.com/Curbal-Data-Labs/Matplotlib-Labs/blob/master/Polar%20charts/Polar%20bar%20chart.ipynb

Comment: it is nice chart but your charts no attached .csv file.So all of Jupyter can't run it. Can you add it into ?
example: `C:\Users\Ruth Pozuelo\Documents\python_examples\data\2018w5.csv`

Comment: Yes, the data is available on data.world (makeover monday 2018 week5). here is a direct link:
https://query.data.world/s/675hw2chsqw5pmkebjcgwpzxom7lht

Comment: Thanks you very much. It works well after change headers. Can you support more data?

2019w5.xlsx
2019w43.csv
2018w6.csv
2018w9.csv
2018w48.csv
2021w13.csv
2019w17.xlsx
2020w5.csv
2018w2.csv

Comment: Not sure what you mean? The data you got is all I have.

Comment: I downloaded your chart [repository](https://github.com/Curbal-Data-Labs/Matplotlib-Labs). That files are missing in your Jupiter files.
Example:  C:\Users\Ruth Pozuelo\Documents\python_examples\data\2018w6.csv,  C:\Users\Ruth Pozuelo\Documents\python_examples\Matplotlib\data\2019w5.xlsx,  C:\Users\Ruth Pozuelo\Documents\python_examples\data\2017w3.csv

Comment: I see what you mean now. You can find all datasets here:
https://www.makeovermonday.co.uk/data/data-sets-2018/